# glibc error: "free(): invalid next size"

Tags: embedded-linux, starttls

I have a program with an error, when I execute `strace -e open myprogram`
I have the following message:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libgnutls.so.28", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/usr/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/usr/lib/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3
open("/usr/lib/libp11-kit.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)       = 3
open("/usr/lib/libtasn1.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libnettle.so.4", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libhogweed.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/libgmp.so.10", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)  = 3
open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
open("/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY)    = 3

--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=509, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=3} ---
before tls_server_init
gnutls_check_version 30105
before gnutls_global_init
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3

*** glibc detected *** /home/myprogram: free(): invalid next size (fast
): 0x01b53200 ***
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=508, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
Aborted
```

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: It seems that `/etc/ld.so.cache` does not exist

Comment: That's not necessarily an error. More likely a call to `free()` has detected that its internal data structures have been corrupted. Go looking for buffer overruns with allocated memory.

Comment: I think is a free() error but the problem comes from the gnutls_global_init(), and I can't change anything in there.

Comment: It's detected in gnutls_global_init. Doesn't mean it is caused by that code. Looks like a buffer overrun or other memory corruption. So possibly a bug somewhere in your code which is corrupting memory that belongs to gnutls_global_init.

Comment: Since it appears to be a memory corruption you may consider using something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to try and detect that.